# Raymarching fractals

Tags: opengl, raytracing

I try to render a fractal according to this tutorial: http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/index.php/2011/08/distance-estimated-3d-fractals-iii-folding-space/comment-page-1/#comment-20302 the one under "A REAL FRACTAL". The problem is, that my ray is missing the fractal, all I get is a black image. I think my rays miss the fractal. My question is:

What sensible defaults should I use for "Scale" and "Iteration"?

Code for generating the fractals:

```
distanceFromPoint(vec3 z) {
  vec3 a1 = vec3(1,1,1);
  vec3 a2 = vec3(-1,-1,1);
  vec3 a3 = vec3(1,-1,-1);
  vec3 a4 = vec3(-1,1,-1);
  vec3 c;
  int n = 0;
  float dist, d;
  while (n < Iterations) {
   c = a1; dist = length(z-a1);
   d = length(z-a2); if (d < dist) { c = a2; dist=d; }
   d = length(z-a3); if (d < dist) { c = a3; dist=d; }
   d = length(z-a4); if (d < dist) { c = a4; dist=d; }
   z = Scale*z-c*(Scale-1.0);
   n++;
  }
return (length(z) ) * pow(Scale, -float(n));
```

Is the construction of the rays correct? Code of my "main" Method:

```
vec2 p = -1.0 + 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / u_ws.xy;
p.x *= u_aspect;

vec3 ro = 1.1*vec3(2.5*sin(0.25*ctime),1.0+1.0*cos(ctime*.13),2.5*cos(0.25*ctime));
vec3 ww = normalize(vec3(0.0) - ro);
vec3 uu = normalize(cross( vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0), ww ));
vec3 vv = normalize(cross(ww,uu));
vec3 rd = normalize( p.x*uu + p.y*vv + 2.5*ww );

float totalDistance = 0.0;
vec4 color = vec4(trace(ro, rd));
```

Comment: Please post the entire shader. Have you even tried it with just rendering spheres?

Comment: check out the work by kali on shadetoy website for examples of perfect work. https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldS3zh

Answer (score 0):

When ray-marching, you should avoid functions like sin / cos because it may become quickly very expensive.
If not sure about how to implement your rays, you can check Inigo Quilez work (very neat):
http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/terrainmarching/terrainmarching.htm

Also worth checking his other samples :
http://www.iquilezles.org/www/index.htm

Looks like your are trying Mikael Hvidtfeldt Christensen's tutorials, have you checked his great shader editor [Fragmentarium](http://syntopia.github.io/Fragmentarium/) ? (many samples too)

It seems that your tutorial page is showing snaps from Fragmentarium.

Ooops, this post looks old..